# Compatibility between SQL server 2005 & 2012 with C++

Tags: c++, sql-server

We are migrating from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012 and from XP to Win7. I thought I would be able to install/upgrade to SQL 2012 on Windows 7, but that has not worked. (I get a message indicating that "can not update because SP4 not installed", I tried to install SP3 and/or SP4 and nothing happens, that is the Select @@version does not change from 9.0.3042.) So, I dumped SQL2005 and installed SQL2012, but now I can not connect to the Server using my original code. I'm pretty sure it has to do with this statement, #import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033\sqldmo.rll" rename_namespace("sqldmo")
Since this uniquely (I assume) identifies the SQL2005 GUID(s?).

So, is this assumption correct?
Is there a better way to connect to the Server that is version independent?
Our program actually creates the database, tables and stored procedures we use.  (All the access to the database tables are through Stored Procedures.)

If this is the way to connect, then can I 'just' change the reference, recompile and everything should work again?

BTW: I'm still using Visual Studio 6. We have VS2012, but I'm not sure if building with that will cause more problems.  Too much work never enough time.....

Thanks for any advice....

Answer (score 0):

DMO was marked deprecated quite a long time ago (2005 as far as I know), with the replacement being SMO (a .NET library). I'm afraid you're not going to be able to just drop in a new DLL and recompile, not by a long shot.

It really depends on what you were doing. I would assume that the DMO code was being used to create the database objects, rather than connect to run queries. If that's the case, then you will need to replace that code and implement something that runs the queries requires to create your database.

If you are actually querying through DMO, then you have a bit more work to do, as you'll need to be connecting via ODBC or something similar which is compatible all the way from 7 -> 2014. There are a lot of examples of how to do that around, but that would be a much better bet.